# Do I have to retain an object before passing it to -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:?

Tags: iphone

I am creating an NSArray inside a method, so I have to give it up with release when I'm done with it. I pass this array to the

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

method. After that, I don't need the array anymore in my method that calls this performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:.

The documentaton doesn't say if anArgument is going to be retained, so I wonder if I had to autorelease it or retain it in order to stay alive. What do you think?

Comment: Quick comment: autorelease wouldn't help anyways because who knows how long the delay would be. It would almost assuredly be longer than the run loop takes to complete.

Comment: `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is guaranteed to run on the next cycle of the run loop (even if the delay is 0.0 seconds), which should mean that the autorelease pool will be emptied.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [performSelector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:) methods retain their receiver and argument.